# dynamic height of UITableViewCell depending upon the Text

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped tableview with a right detail cell layout. Now I got my data back from my server. 
Sometimes it happens that I got back a very large text. So the tableviewCell should be higher than the others. You can see the screenshot of my problem over here.

[image]

Like you can see in my first cell I have a very large text. Now I want that the height of the cell grows with the length of the text, so i can always see the entire text instead off the '...' This is what I have in code at te moment.

```
#define PADDING 10.0f
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Subscription *sub = [_dictTask valueForKeyPath:@"subscription"];

    NSArray *meta = sub.meta.allObjects;

    NSString *text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sum_value"];
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width - PADDING * 3, 1000.0f)];

    return textSize.height + PADDING * 3;
}
```

**EDIT**
Code I have at the moment.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Subscription *sub = [_dictTask valueForKeyPath:@"subscription"];

    NSArray *meta = sub.meta.allObjects;

    NSString *text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sum_value"];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(330.0f, 400);  // Make changes in width as per your label requirement.

    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return  textSize.height;
}
```

And this is the result.

[image]

**EDIT CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Subscription *sub = [_dictTask valueForKeyPath:@"subscription"];
    NSArray *meta = sub.meta.allObjects;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        cell.textLabel.text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sum_label"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sum_value"];

        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0
                                               green:102/255.0
                                                blue:102/255.0
                                               alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
        return cell;



}
```

Comment: +1 for your efforts. Though there are many similar questions previously asked. ;-)

Comment: `CGSizeMake(330.0f, 400);` try `MAXFLOAT` instead 400 and let me know what happens.

Comment: Also please post `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap` in your code.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sum_value"];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(330.0f, MAXFLOAT);  // Make changes in width as per your label requirement. 

    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return  textSize.height;
}
```

Moreover you need to set two properties of detailTextLabel`also in datasource method`cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
   cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
 }
```

- **numberofLines property describes:**

  This property controls the maximum number of lines to use in order to fit the label’s text into its bounding rectangle. The default value for this property is 1. To remove any maximum limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but this isn't working. also I needed to return textSize.height. Because it excpected a CGFloat.

Comment: Yeah. Missed that. Changed code. In my implementation this logic worked.

Comment: I've edited my post. Something is still not correct. I added also the code in my CellForRowAtIndex like you suggested. Appreciated your help !

Comment: YOu provided `heightForRowAtIndexPath` twice. No sign of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.. :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23101/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-rohan-patel)

Comment: You can find me in [NSChat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/nschat) room. And in fact there are more knowledgable people than me. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            Subscription *sub = [_dictTask valueForKeyPath:@"subscription"];

            NSArray *meta = sub.meta.allObjects;

            NSString *text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sum_value"];
            UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0];
            CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(330.0f, MAXFLOAT);  // Make changes in width as per your label requirement.

            CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return  textSize.height + 20; }
```

Then, consider using unique cell identifiers.  The idea here is that reusing the cell will result in mismatched heights for the contents.  (Some people don't like the idea of unique identifiers, but they work and they're not problematic unless your table is going to be huge.)  Accordingly, try this:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Subscription *sub = [_dictTask valueForKeyPath:@"subscription"];
    NSArray *meta = sub.meta.allObjects;

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row]];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell.textLabel.text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sum_label"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sum_value"];

        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0
                                               green:102/255.0
                                                blue:102/255.0
                                               alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
}
        return cell;
}
```